# How to set it up to switch between tabs using TAB key on Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, tabs

On the image below this is what I want to do. I want to be able to switch tab options with TAB key.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### save dialog specific shortcuts:

To save, simply press <kbd>return</kbd>

To cancel, hit <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

If you do not want so save, hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>backpace</kbd>

### using <kbd>tab</kbd>:

If you want to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, you should enable keyboard access by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> *Note: Depending on your setup, you might need to additionally press <kbd>fn</kbd> to use the function keys.*

Once you've enabled keyboard access, you should see an additional blue glow around the currently selected button. You can then cycle with <kbd>tab</kbd> (holding <kbd>shift</kbd> to go backwards) and select your option by pressing <kbd>space</kbd>.

Comment: ok, when I enable it, how to turn it off?

Comment: The same way you turned it on - ctrl+F7

Comment: actually: ctrl + fn + F7

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk well yes, if you set up your function keys to require fn within system preferences > keyboard