# How to choose an option in some windows with keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard

For example, when I close an app with some changes without saving ir before. A window asks me if I want to save or not.

[image]

In Windows I can choose between these options with <kbd>Tab</kbd> but in Mac does not work.

EDIT: To save the document It's obviously that I can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but I want to know how can I choose the other options.

PS: sorry for my english, I'm from Argentina

EDIT2: I found the answer here but I don't know how to mark as 'Answered': [How to set it up to switch between tabs using TAB key on Macbook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169873/how-to-set-it-up-to-switch-between-tabs-using-tab-key-on-macbook?rq=1)